# Extra parameters for startLogging (Twisted)?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

In Twisted docs, [startLogging API](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.log.startLogging.html) supports *a and **kw extra arguments. What can I use these for?

Answer (score 2):

There's just one more parameter you can pass, `setStdout`.  See the documentation for `startLoggingWithObserver` for details about what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure they are used at all. See [Samples](http://nullege.com/codes/search/twisted.python.log.startLogging) and [documentation](http://docs.huihoo.com/python/twisted/howto/logging.html) where they are not used nor mentioned. Also, after [reviewing the source code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-9.0.0/twisted/python/log.py#L572), it doesn't seem to use them.